# The Head and Skip Head blocks do not appear to be writing to all file sinks

Tags: gnuradio-companion

I have the following flowgraph to capture a small specified band. It seems that the final file sink never gets written to because it always has a 0 byte size. [image: flowgraph]

This is the first time I have tried to use the Head and Skip Head blocks, so I am not sure if it has something to do with them or not. Initially only the first file was being written to, but as I increased the vec_size variable the second, third, and fourth files were being written to as well. No matter how large I make the vec_size variable though, I can't seem to get any data written to the fifth file sink. Does anyone know if it's an issue with the Head/Skip Head blocks or possibly something else I'm not seeing?

Comment: Hm, 50MS/s is quite heavy, and I hope you know that this will take serious PC power to process. In fact, I'm almost certain that a 1.024·10⁶-point FFT will not be possible in real time. So, probably, your USRP will have to drop samples like crazy, and your console output will be full of the corresponding warning letters?

Comment: The 50MS/s was more hopeful than practical. I am using a USRP B200-mini which has an available bandwidth of 56MHz. I dropped the vec_size variable down to 1024 and now there is an output to each file with each file being 4.1kB. I will probably cut the sample rate down to about 25MS/s, or 22MS/s at the lowest. I also don't intend to do any real time analysis.